Receiving Master Data Type as a result
How to get parent model  as a result. I want to get  MasterData type as a result. i want to use where condition in Attributes but i want to receive Master Data Type as a result
 var result= MasterData.SelectMany(ca => ca.sections).Where(x =>MasterDataAttId_All.Contains(x.SectionId)).ToList();


I guess you're trying to var result = MasterData.Where(md => md.sections.Any(x => MasterDataAttId_All.Contains(x.SectionId))).ToList() let me know if it works! If it does, I'll properly post it as an answer :)
